# I need a new line break ( <br>) in Unicode encoding, using $translateProvider in a resouce file

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using angularJS translateProvider and in the resource file i have a prefix "paragraph \u003cbr /\u003e paragraph" witch gives me. `paragraph <br /> paragraph`.
but what i need is a break-line (or new line) like so

paragraph

paragraph

I would appreciate the help thank.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is really possible to pass unicode symbols in angular-translate. Almost same questions was in issues to that package on github: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/554, https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/595, and answer was just to use `<br>` tag in translation string.

But i think, may be you can write some variable or placeholder in translation strings, and after translation in Controller / Directive, you can replace it with `str.replace('SOMEPLACEHOLDER', '\n')`?

Comment: in getting a \u003e non-breaking space with tyat so i though there is a new line code..well see thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should update the Sanitize Value Strategy of the $translateProvider.
In the config phase set

```
 $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escaped');
```

Also you should include **ngSanitize** as a dependency and also **angular-sanitize.js**.

Comment: I'm getting     $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escaped');

Comment: See in the example how you should use translate in the views because if you use like a filer (key | translate ) it won't work

Comment: I injected it right. and no errors but it shoots strait <br/> on the html page. i need the the new line

Comment: Can you please provide the code line how you use the translation in the html

Comment: "prenfix": {
    "MainText": "We have simplified the complex task of putting together a full-feature adaptable web application. <br/> onotherParagraph "  },

Comment: In the html page try to translate the "MainText" as 
<p translate="MainText"></p>